# React native Context API

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

Hi I am Try to create demo with React natvie context API

---- BlogContext.js ----

```
import React from 'react';

const BlogContext = React.createContext();

export const BlogProvider = ({ children }) => {
    return (
        <BlogContext.Provider value= {5}> {children} </BlogContext.Provider>
    );
};

export default BlogContext;
```

Application JS File

----- App.js ----

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
} from 'react-native';

import {
  Header,
  LearnMoreLinks,
  Colors,
  DebugInstructions,
  ReloadInstructions,
} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

import IndexScreen from './AllScreens/IndexScreen';
import {BlogProvider} from './AllScreens/BlogContext';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
  <BlogProvider>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={IndexScreen} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </BlogProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

getting below error

```
Error: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component.

This error is located at:
    in BlogProvider (at App.js:38)
    in App (at renderApplication.js:45)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:106)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:132)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)
```

Index screen Code:

-----IndexScreen.js ------

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react';
import {View,Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
//import BlogContext from './BlogContext';

const IndexScreen = () => {

    //const value = useContext(BlogContext);

    return (
        <View> 
            <Text>Index Screen</Text>
        </View>
    );
};

const styels = StyleSheet.create({
    
});

export default IndexScreen;
```

Comment: I think the error message is quite self explanatory. You're having an empty space or other markup considered as string on that line.

Comment: Show your `IndexScreen` screen code. There might be Text component which have invalid string

Comment: @NooruddinLakhani updated, i already checked that and without context project is working